# Disable auto-rotate does not work in certain apps

Tags: auto-rotation, gyroscope

In android 11 I disabled auto-rotate of the screen by setting to "off" Settings > Display > Auto Rotate.

however in certain apps that doesn't seem to make any difference and the screen is still rotated when I move the phone orientation

I assume that's because the app developer has decided to override the android auto-rotate setting, or would there be any other reason for this behavior?

Alternatively is there a way to set the gyroscope manually so I can set the orientation of the phone without it being automatically detected

Comment: It is not only app, but also view specific inside each app: I had a new app where disabled auto-rotate worked perfectly just the "latest news" view had auto-rotation always active.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have since located an app called Ultimate Rotation Control that enables locking on the rotation which offers a 7 day trial. I was not able to find any other solution to this words cannot describe how infuriating this can be!

Comment: Yes, the developer may override this, mostly for user's convenient (e.g. playing games exclusively for landscape mode will be awful if it's rotated to portrait, and vice versa), or otherwise because the app hasn't supported layout for both mode and the dev thinks it may have buggy behavior.